# Paginação Java WEB

Tags: java, aplicação-web, paginação

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Java Web e preciso saber qual é a melhor forma para paginar registro no *grid* e se, dependendo de como foi desenvolvido, posso ter problemas de performance como parâmetro de "Data" e se isso pode influenciar na hora de exporta um relatório em .CSV.

Faço a paginação na própria aplicação ou usando o banco de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta é bem genérica/ampla então não é possível dar uma resposta muito concreta.

Dessa forma, seguem algumas observações/respostas sendo que todas partem do princípio que não tem nenhuma tecnologia definida:

> Faço a paginação na própria aplicação ou usando o banco de dados?

Eu faria a paginação no banco de dados.

A view envia as informações de qual página está e quantas linhas devem ser buscadas e o banco realiza essa operação. Dificilmente eu carregaria tudo na view e paginaria só na view. Faria isso apenas em casos em que o volume de dados fosse extremamente baixo e que isso não aumentaria conforme o tempo.

> Posso ter problemas de performance como parâmetro de "Data"?

Não. A não ser que você faça várias conversões de formatos, ordenação e etc.

> Isso pode influenciar na hora de exportar um relatório em .csv?

Fazendo a paginação no banco, na hora exportar, aí sim você deve fazer uma consulta para retornar tudo do banco, pois se exportar o que está sendo exibido, bom, só vai exportar o que está sendo exibido hehe. Ao executar a "consulta toda" no banco, obviamente vai demorar um pouco mais para recuperar os dados, mas irá funcionar.

Caso o volume de dados seja muito grande, deve-se fazer alguns `flushs` durante a exportação. Flush é a ação de transferir os dados da memória para o arquivo em si, pois se manter tudo na memória e o volume de dados for alto, uma hora você provavelmente receberá um `OutOfMemoryError` ou algo do tipo.

---

Apenas como referência, [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--) está a documentação do método `flush()` da classe `OutputStream` que explica, nos detalhes, o que é feito.